# Heroku Deplyment Issue

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have designed and deployed an application using Heroku and Amazon Domains.
On Heroku Dashboard it says it is deployed, however, when navigating to my custom domain as routed through Google Domains DNS, on Chrome, I get

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
[my domain address] sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

on Safari, I get this:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

In Heroku CLI, I get various repetitions of this:

```
2020-06-23T22:24:55.547063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-23T22:24:55.549715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-23T22:25:09.117253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-23T22:25:12.260416+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-23T22:25:12.260435+00:00 app[web.1]: > devsite@0.1.0 start /app
2020-06-23T22:25:12.260435+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-06-23T22:25:12.260435+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-23T22:25:15.391173+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.65.34/
2020-06-23T22:25:15.391961+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-06-23T22:25:15.392148+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-06-23T22:25:15.392299+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-06-23T22:25:15.392676+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-06-23T22:25:15.392678+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-23T22:25:15.557069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-06-23T22:25:15.600977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-23T22:33:38.336119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=[my domain address] request_id=601ec2aa-02c8-4587-a0cd-fdd1d5b4811f fwd="104.34.247.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I only have client side code that I have deployed with using React.  I am not calling any server  or database for anything.

I am seeing on some posts that I need to create a server.js file, route into it from package.json and rebundle, I wanted to check this knowledge base first.

package.json is built from Create React App template

```
{
  "name": "devsite",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "heroku": "^7.42.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-social-badge": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `npm start` script `react-scripts start` won't work. You need to wrap an express server around your build files and serve that.

Comment: Thanks @TinNguyen that's what I did and it worked.

Comment: If possible please provide a minimal reproducible answer guide how you did it because this question gets asked a lot on StackOverflow